# Using no_story with C# Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use **no_story=1** to avoid posting in the user wall when an album has been created.

But I don't know where to pass such parameter, I've used:

```
var fb = new FacebookWebClient(_accessToken);
Dictionary<string, object> album = new Dictionary<string, object>();
System.Random rnd = new Random();
string name = "MyAlbum" + rnd.Next(150).ToString();
album.Add("name", name);
**album.Add("no_story", 1);**
album.Add("location", "MyLocation");
album.Add("privacy", "{\"value\": \"CUSTOM\", \"friends\": \"SELF\"}");
dynamic aid = fb.Post("/me/albums", album);
```

and also used:

```
dynamic aid = fb.Post("/me/albums?no_story=1", album);
```

Neither way is working, I still see when the album has been created in my wall.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems that no_story is per photo and not per album; since the wall shows the photos only. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct in the sense that you are adding the parameter the right way. However, this is not a valid parameter when creating an album so Facebook's Graph API is simply ignoring it. You can see the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/